# C# equivalent of imbue and numpunct

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to find the C# equivalent of the following in C++.  This is purely for fun

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

class CommaSep : public std::numpunct<TCHAR>
{
public:
     CommaSep(TCHAR thousands_sep, const char* grouping)
        :m_thousands_sep(thousands_sep),
         m_grouping(grouping){}
protected:
     TCHAR do_thousands_sep() const{return m_thousands_sep;}
     std::string do_grouping() const {return m_grouping;}
private:
     TCHAR m_thousands_sep;
     std::string m_grouping;
};

int main()
{
    double number = 1234567.1235;
    std::locale comma_locale(std::locale(), new CommaSep(_T(','), "\03"));
    std::locale indian_locale(std::locale(), new CommaSep(_T(','), "\02\02\03"));
    std::locale weird_locale(std::locale(), new CommaSep(_T(','), "\02\01\03"));

    std::wcout.imbue(comma_locale);
    std::wcout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << number << std::endl;
    std::wcout.imbue(indian_locale);
    std::wcout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << number << std::endl;
    std::wcout.imbue(weird_locale);
    std::wcout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << number << std::endl;
}
```

The result is

```
1,234,567.12
123,45,67.12
1,234,5,67.12
```

It does exactly what I tell it.  I tried the following in C#.  The code is a lot smaller (hooray) but the compiler just ignores the formatting and does its own thing (boo hiss)

```
namespace imbuecs
{
    class Imbue
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int bignum = 123456789;

            System.Console.WriteLine(bignum.ToString("########0"));
            // Indian
            System.Console.WriteLine(bignum.ToString("##,###,##,#0"));
            System.Console.WriteLine(bignum.ToString("###,###,##0"));
            // Chinese
            System.Console.WriteLine(bignum.ToString("#,####,###0"));
        }
    }
}
```

What I got was

```
123456789
123,456,789  expected 12,345,67,89
123,456,789
123,456,789  expected 1,2345,6789
```

I can write huge swathes of code for doing this but I'm wondering if there is a simple way of doing this.

Comment: "is a lot smaller" - you could have wrote completely wrong code in C++ too and it would be shorter too :).. If you really care you should be using appropriate `CultureInfo` to do locale specific formatting and not some manual solution.

Comment: CultureInfo won't do the weird locale, which is what I generally use it for.  Sometimes I have to display with separators in non-standard positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx), when specifiying custom formatting, the comma (emphasis mine):

> Serves as both a group separator and a number scaling specifier. As a group separator, it inserts a localized group separator character between each group. As a number scaling specifier, **it divides a number by 1000** for each comma specified.

So it causes the number to be grouped into 3 digits. If you want to make your own format, you need to enclose the comma in single quotes to render it as a literal string. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine(bignum.ToString("##','###','##','#0"));
Console.WriteLine(bignum.ToString("#','####','###0"));
```

Will output:

```
12,345,67,89
1,2345,6789
```

Another alternative is to use the `NumberFormatInfo` object with the [NumberGroupSizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes(v=vs.110).aspx) property. For example:

```
var nfi = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
//First group is 2 digits, the rest are 3 digits
nfi.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 2, 3 }; 

Console.WriteLine(bignum.ToString("#,#0", nfi));
```